# Take all ontology classes to an arraylist from .owl file using Java

Tags: java, jena, ontology

I want to take all ontology class names to an array. I used following code. It print its output as one class  `[http://localhost/new/Car Price]` . But I need to take only class name as `Car Price`. What are the changes I need to do?

```
                   m.read("http://localhost/new/sample.owl");
                   ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classes = m.listClasses();      
                   public String extractName() {   ----------------error: Syntax error on token "String", @ expected
                   while (classes.hasNext()) {
                       OntClass all= (OntClass) classes.next();
                       String cla = all.toString();
                       String members[] = cla.split("/");
                       nameIndex = members.length - 1;
                       return member[nameIndex];
                       }                                            
                        OntClass all= (OntClass) classes.next();
                        System.out.println(all.extractName());
                       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing your print with your list `classlist`, for this reason you see [ ] in your output.

If the format of your value contains and  is always separate by `/`, you could create a helper method as:

```
public static String extractName(OntoClass ontoClass) {
   String members[] = ontoClass.toString().split("/");
   nameIndex = members.length - 1;
   return members[nameIndex];
}
```

and you print the extracted name at this line:

```
OntClass all= (OntClass) classes.next();
System.out.println(extractName(all));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I add "cla " instead of "http://localhost/new/Car Price". It gave an error in "public String extractName()"  as "Syntax error on token "String", @ expected". Where I need to change for that?

Comment: you should use the member of your class related to your value in the helper method or this.toString()

Comment: You should put the helper method as member of your class OntClass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103382/discussion-between-jesus-zavarce-and-leel).